# c++ regex expression error (unhandled exception)

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to select the )9  in the string ss,
to replace it with )*9

I am getting an unhandled expression error at the 2nd line (def of ee).
I have tried all the combinations of line 2 I can think of (including double escaping the d).

```
std::string ss ("1 + (3+2)9 - 2 ");
std::regex ee ("(\\)\d)([^ ]");

std::string result;
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), ee, "*$2");
std::cout << result;
```

Comment: Do you know what `'\d'` is? [Because it doesn't mean "digit" like most regexes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). Try escaping that backslash. (I'd expect the compiler to be issuing a warning about this)

Comment: What compiler version are you using?

Comment: I just updated the description to include I tried \\d.  This documentation says "\d" is part of c++ regex (that perl is the default regex type):  
cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/  -  
boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

Comment: MS Visual Studio Express 2013.

Comment: @MikeSmith: The _bytes_ `\d` are part of a C++ regex.  However, the _literal_ `"\d"` does not contain the bytes `\d`.  It's very confusing, and if you turn up the warnings slightly, the compiler will warn you about this.

Comment: Regex is not a particularly good fit for parsing expressions (nested parens/sub expressions etc...) but I suspect you are looking for this: `std::regex ee ("(\\)\\d)([^ ])");`

Comment: What is a better way to convert all )8 or 8) to )*8 or 8*( ?
I'm sending the string through an existing parser, but that code does not compute (2)8 as 16.  It's expecting (2)*8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all your backslashes:

```
"(\\)\\d)([^ ]"
```

Otherwise you could be sending a control character to the regex, not the two characters `\` and `d`.

Also, you either need a regex backslash for the second `(`:

```
"(\\)\\d)\\([^ ]"
```

or you need to add a matching close-parenthesis:

```
"(\\)\\d)([^ ])"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was missing that last parenthesis.
Now the question is, why does the code above print out the original string, without the "*" added between the ) and the 9.

Comment: I will post this question separately.